# vSphereAPI get nic info

Tags: vsphere

Based on vSphere API, modify the parameters of the network card for VMS with historical stock. Its interface requires that the input parameters transmitted should include all the information of the VM's original network card (gateway, mask, DNS, etc.), but there is no interface available at present. This technical point is stuck. I want to find someone who understands R & D for advice

Comment: There are two API services to interact with VM's NICs, which service are you using and which action are you using? It sounds like you're using the vSphere Automation API and a `PUT` or `PATCH`  whereas you would find more success with a `POST`

Comment: Now it's through VM Getguest, do you have a better way to get relevant information? At present, the information obtained in this way is incomplete